# How to release an vb.net class libary object from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, release, vba

as the performance of Excel VBA was to poor for my calculations, I migrated my code to a VB.net class libary which I add as a reference in Excel. I am using VBA for all my read and write function, but the processing is done in my dll.

Everything is working fine except the release of the used memory. I already implemented in my following function in the VB.net class libary.

```
  Public Sub releaseObject(ByRef obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    End Try
End Sub
```

However Excel is still keepting the memory. What do I have to do, to finally release my object?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: `However Excel is still keepting the memory`, what makes you believe its actual?

Comment: When I check with the Task Manager the memory consumtion of Excel, I can see, that before I create with VBA an object of my class, the usage is around 25MB. When I create an object and do my calculations the consumption goes up to 150MB and stayes at this level even when I release the object.

Comment: See this link http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/. Specially the `TWO DOT Rule` and `Close Excel and Clean Up`

Comment: Thank you for this link. You made a really nice tutorial. However I am using a class libary, which is  created in VB.net, in VBA as a reference. So I am not directly accessing Excel using Interop. The Problem is now that i can't release my class libary objects in VBA.